# Removing Form rounded corners on maximize

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using a custom function to create a rounded cornered form. My Question is pretty simple, how could I remove those corners (aka going back to a regular rectangle form) when maximizing the window ?

On Resize event, I'm checking the WindowState to see if it's maximized, and try to redraw the form borders, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public partial class ClientListForm : Form
    {
        public ClientListForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RoundBorderForm(this);
        }

        private void ClientListForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
            {
                SharpBorderForm(this);
            } else
            {
                RoundBorderForm(this);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
        public static void RoundBorderForm(Form frm)
        {

            Rectangle Bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, frm.Width, frm.Height);
            int CornerRadius = 18;
            System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath path = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
            path.AddArc(Bounds.X, Bounds.Y, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 180, 90);
            path.AddArc(Bounds.X + Bounds.Width - CornerRadius, Bounds.Y, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 270, 90);
            path.AddArc(Bounds.X + Bounds.Width - CornerRadius, Bounds.Y + Bounds.Height - CornerRadius, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 0, 90);
            path.AddArc(Bounds.X, Bounds.Y + Bounds.Height - CornerRadius, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 90, 90);
            path.CloseAllFigures();

            frm.Region = new Region(path);
            frm.Show();
        }

        public static void SharpBorderForm(Form frm)
        {
            frm.Region = new Region(new Rectangle(0, 0, frm.Width, frm.Height));
            frm.Show();
        }
```

The window appears maximized but I still have the rounded corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `frm.Show()` is doing nothing, as your `frm` is already shown. You need to call `Invalidate` method in this case. The call for `frm.Show()` in `frm` constructor is strange anyway:\

Also, your `SharpBorderForm` and `RoundBorderForm` doesn't need to be static:

```
private void RoundBorderForm()
{
    var bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);
    var cornerRadius = 18;
    var path = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();

    path.AddArc(bounds.X, bounds.Y, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 180, 90);
    path.AddArc(bounds.X + bounds.Width - cornerRadius, bounds.Y, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 270, 90);
    path.AddArc(bounds.X + bounds.Width - cornerRadius, bounds.Y + bounds.Height - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 0, 90);
    path.AddArc(bounds.X, bounds.Y + bounds.Height - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 90, 90);
    path.CloseAllFigures();

    Region = new Region(path);
    Invalidate();
}

private void SharpBorderForm()
{
    Region = new Region(new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height));
    Invalidate();
}
```

Also, you don't need to subscribe to `Resize` event here. You can just override `OnResize` protected method:

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnResize(e);

    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
        SharpBorderForm();
    else
        RoundBorderForm();
}
```